# Comma delimited list to Django template

Tags: python, django

I'm building website on Django and this is my problem. Btw, I won't post my views.py or models.py or html file because I need to understand the technique.

User enters tags separated by commas in a field on my webpage.

All I want is to have them like this
[tags example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0J7AV.png) to be able to format them.

It would be great to be able to pass them to Templates as follows:

```
{% for i in tags %} 
    <p class="nice"> {{ i }} </p> 
{% endfor %}
```

But I've spent 3 days looking for solution, so any approach will do.
Thanks.

Comment: You need to at least share the part of your view where you are adding `tags` to your context

Comment: What is `tags`? Is it a string, list or something else?

Comment: Tags can be list, or string, or set as you wish. The problem is that I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Tags argument in views.py is set via POST method. Is it ok, or maybe you can offer a better option?

Comment: Can you at least add an example of the POST data? The answer to your question is completely dependant on it

Comment: `def create_publication(request):
    a = Publication(tags = request.POST['tags'],...
    a.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('publications:index'))`

@IainShelvington set aside my approach, how would you try to solve it?

Comment: Not adding your views, models or templates makes it a lot harder to understand what you want to achieve. So I understand, you have a model `Publication` and a view `publications:index` that lists publications and you want to add tags to publications and display them?

Comment: @IainShelvington That is correct, I want to be able to split those tags and display them **the way I want**